# C codes in windows and linux

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me why this code work in windows and not compiled in linux?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    char myname[10];
    printf("Please Enter your name:");
    scanf("%s",&myname);
    printf("Welcome %s\n",myname);
    strcpy(myname,"DefaultName");
    printf("so your name now is %s\n",myname);
}
```

I use a Dev c++ in windows to compile.
I use a gcc or g++ in linux to compile.

So what the wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer: But add `#include<string.h>`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Is `main()` even a valid signature?

Comment: The Error is :file.c: In function ‘main’:.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%s",&myname);
     ^
file.c:10:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’ [enabled by default]
     strcpy(myname,"DefaultName");
     ^

Comment: What error message are you getting? Is compiling under Linux not working, or running it on Linux not working? One possibility if it isn't running is that you have a buffer overflow problem that can corrupt the return of the main function ("DefaultName" requires 12 butes of storage, bt you only allocated 10)

Comment: Remove ampersand `&` from the second argument in `scanf` call.

Comment: I want to test buffer overflow , when I wrote the code in windows it compiled fine , but in linux there is error , I changed the 10 bytes to 15 , but its still not working in linux ! , so what the wrong?

Comment: Just by the way, you should get spammed with compiler warnings at least in both. this code looks very..... bad at all ^^

Comment: I removed & , still not work.

Comment: #Zaibis , thanks for your note , but I want to know why the same code working in windows and not working in linux ?!!

Comment: You have already received an answer: overwriting the array with more data than the array can hold causes Undefined Behavior. Depending on the compiler itself, its settings and the execution environment you may overwrite some vital data of your process, which causes a crash, or you may overwrite some 'no-man's land' which appears harmless. Do as you are adviced—write a safe, correct code, build and then compare how it works in different systems.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code exhibits Undefined Behavior which means that anything can happen. This is because you try to copy `"DefaultName"` that has more than 10 bytes(12 bytes including the `\0` character at the end of the string) into `myname` that can hold atmost 9 characters +1 for the `\0` at the end. Also,

```
scanf("%s",&myname);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%s",myname);
```

This is because the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element(`char*`) which is the same as

```
scanf("%s",&myname[0]);
```

Increase the safety by limiting the amount of characters that `scanf` reads so that you prevent buffer overflows by using

```
scanf("%9s",myname);
```

Also, you need to include `string.h` in order to use the `strcpy` function. You also need to know that `main()` isn't a valid declaration. It needs to be either

```
int main()
```

Or

```
int main(void)
```

in newer standards of C(C99,C11). You also need to supply

```
return 0;
```

at the end of the function. Usually, a program returns 0 on success and 1 on failure(due to some problem).

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that strings in C doesn't really have a length, so it uses a special character to tell the end of the string, the so-called "null" character (`'\0'`).

So if you have an array of ten characters, it can only hold a string of *nine* characters since there must be space for the terminator character as well.

The string `"DefaultName"` is *twelve* character including the string terminator, and when you copy it over to your array you will write beyond the limits of the array, and that leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you increase the size of the array by two characters, the string will fit, but it will only fit strings eleven (not including terminator) characters or less.

Side note: The string literal `"DefaultName"` is actually a pointer to a constant array of twelve characters, whose contents is `"DefaultName\0"`.

Another side note: Arrays decays to pointers to their first element, so you don't have to use the address-of `&` operator on arrays when passing them to functions. In fact, I consider it to be a bad habit to use the address-of operator when passing variables supposed to hold strings as arguments to functions. The reason is that often when you programming in C you will be handling pointers instead of arrays, and if you by mistake use the address-of operator on a pointer you will again ave *undefined behavior* and you then pass a pointer *to the pointer*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `<string.h>` or `<cstring>` to compile this code in gcc for the `strcpy()` function.

Also, you need to increase the size of your array to fit `"DefaultName"`, so ideally your `myname` array should be of size `strlen("DefaultName")+1`. Also, change

```
scanf("%s",&myname);
```

to

```
scanf("%s",myname);
```

because `myname` is already a *pointer* pointing to the first element of the `char` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(myname,"DefaultName");
```

The mistake is here please make sure the string fits into the array before using `strcpy()` safer is to use `strlcpy()`

Your array can just hold 10 characters including `\0` but you are trying to write more characters to it than it can hold leading to undefined behavior.

Make sure your array can hold the data which you are trying to write or use a safer function like `memcpy()` or `strlcpy()`(Not a standard) which takes care of buffer overflow.